# Heroku Row Limit

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

Why does Heroku have a row limit on their Hobby plan if there is already an overall database size limit? I'm confused because I've reached my row limit, but I'm nowhere near the size limit. Does the amount of rows you store affect what it costs for them to manage it or is that cost only affected by the amount of bytes in your data?

Edit: Also, what constitutes a row, because I added 50 items to a table but it only added one row to my row limit? I thought each item you add to a table is a "row" on the table.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks us to speculate about why a private entity made a particular decision. [We can't answer customer service questions here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/354577).

Comment: But obviously other people in the community feel otherwise, or they would try to close the question as well instead of give their educated guesses. The whole point of this community is to spread information and knowledge about the tech world to those who don't have it so I'm confused why you would try to stifle that process just because you, or even people like you, don't want to bother with this particular niche.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is to stop people using custom data types to store more than 1 row worth of info in a single row. They want to limit the amount of data people can store so they limit the number of rows, but to do this without limiting row size they also need an overall size limit.

Answer (score 0):

The Heroku Postgres dev plan will be limited to 10,000 rows. Not limit had been enforced. This is a global limit.